# How to enable haptic feedback in Samsung Galaxy Y?

Tags: settings, vibration, samsung-galaxy-y, haptic-feedback

Actually I had the haptic feedback option enabled by default when I bought the Samsung Galaxy Y mobile. But it seems that somebody has changed the Settings. So I would like to know how to enable haptic feedback in Samsung Galaxy Y?

But I need it badly. Anybody please help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SGY has tactile feedback *only*, but **NO** haptic feedback. If you require a reference, have a look at [this xda thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1493642). But, there are many (almost everything) custom keyboard apps that provide haptics at the Play Store.

If you love your built-in keyboard so much and don't want other keyboards, then you have a choice. Just root your phone. Use a root explorer. Peek into `/system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl` using a text editor (some apps have in-built editors). There is a list of all keys that your keyboard has (including the menu, back, volume, lock & home keys).

Change from "whatever value they are" to `WAKE_DROPPED` and reboot your phone. That's all. Now, you'll definitely have haptics for every key you've changed.

> Well, If you aren't aware of rooting, please **don't do it**. It may void your warranty. There are a lot of posts here that may help you with rooting. For instance, check out [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting)